# ESP8266 Flash - Maximize SPIFFS size

Tags: esp8266

the board i use has **1MB Flash Size**. My program however downloads 512K+ of data for processing.

Arduino Options i see are:

[image]

Ideally i would like to use 1MB of SPIFFS, is this even possible?

I don't use OTA, and compile with:

[image]

To minimise the footprint of the main sketch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to get a ESP with more flash for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Even if you don't use OTA, your program is stored in flash. If you have 1MB of flash, there's no way you can use all 1MB for SPIFFS; that would leave no space for your program.

Here's [a page showing how flash is divided up in an Arduino environment](https://esp8266.github.io/Arduino/versions/2.0.0/doc/filesystem.html).

Even if you eliminate space for OTA images and the EEPROM, the Arduino environment will still reserve space for the sketch itself and for its wifi config and possibly a little more data.

You can never use 100% of the flash storage for SPIFFS.